# How does Chrome update without UAC

Tags: c#

I just try to understand the Google update service (aka Omaha) and can't find any information about how Omaha updates Chrome without the UAC Prompt?! Or without any Administrator privileges.

I am looking for a way to lunch a update service that can Update a Application in the Program  folder (without UAC / Administrator privileges) just like Omaha does, but i can't find any documentation regarding that topic. Tried browsing the source code a bit thought but i couldn't find anything that helps.

In fact only the Installation should require Administrator Rights, but the update should not.
Any "easy" way to achieve this in C#?

Comment: Workaround: Put the executable and related files somewhere in the user directory. It might be "dirty" but it works.

Comment: as you said "dirty" :) i prefere some clean solution. the user itself should not have access to the files if he lacks the administrator rights.

Comment: Putting the executable in the user directory is necessary, not dirty, if you want to let non-administrators use the program. But in that case you wouldn't even need a windows service. Only when a windows service is reaching into a user's directory would i call it dirty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chrome installs a Windows Service, which is always running and preforms the update. The service runs as SYSTEM and so can perform the update without UAC prompt.

See:

- https://support.google.com/installer/answer/98805?hl=en
- http://omaha.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/OmahaOverview.html (Execution model section)

Comment: +1, Also for a per user install, it installs to the user's profile directory, of which the user has control over, so no UAC prompt required.

Comment: I read that already somewhere but i don't want to install my application into the users Directory. Thanks for making clear that a per user installation installs to a different location

Comment: Firefox uses a similar process: https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2011/10/04/mozilla-firefox-and-silent-updates/